# RelayCommand for button inside a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button inside a TextBox.I want to Bind Command for my button.But It not working when I click on button.
Here is TextBox Template in App.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Name="PART_ContentHost"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Margin="10,0" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding CmdRandom, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"
            Height="15"
            Width="15"
            Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
    string getrnd;
    public string GetRnd {
        set {
            getrnd = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GetRnd");
        }
        get {
            return getrnd;
        }
    }
    public ICommand CmdRandom {
        set {
            cmdrnd = value;
        }
        get {
            cmdrnd = cmdrnd ?? new RelayCommand(x => BindRandom(), x => true);
            return cmrnd;
        }
    }

   void BindRandom()
   {
        GetRnd = new RandomChar();
   }
```

My TextBox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtName" Style="{StaticResource txtRnd}" MaxLength="63" Text="{Binding GetRnd, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a property on an ancestor:

```
{Binding DataContext.CmdRandom, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}}
```

More info:

```
Binding RelativeSource={
RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemType}}
```

The default attribute of `RelativeSource` is the `Mode` property.  A complete set of valid values is given here ([from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesourcemode.aspx)):

- *PreviousData* Allows you to bind the previous data item (not that control that contains the data item) in the list of data items being displayed.
- *TemplatedParent* Refers to the element to which the template (in which the data-bound element exists) is applied. This is similar to setting a TemplateBindingExtension and is only applicable if the Binding is within a template.
- *Self* Refers to the element on which you are setting the binding and allows you to bind one property of that element to another property on the same element.
- *FindAncestor* Refers to the ancestor in the parent chain of the data-bound element. You can use this to bind to an ancestor of a specific type or its subclasses. This is the mode you use if you want to specify AncestorType and/or AncestorLevel.

Comment: Thank for the help!getting: BindingExpression path error: 'CmdRandom' property not found on 'object' ''TextBox' (Name='txtName')'. target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand').What does it mean?

Comment: Thank for your information.It working!But RandomChar taking a lot of memory.